# pandoc markdown keep section numeration among different files

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is it possible to keep section numeration between different files?

For instance, I have this file:

```
 ---
 title: Title
 number_sections: true
 output: latex
 graphics: yes
 header-includes:
   - '\usepackage{graphics}'
 ---
           
    # Section 1
    
    ## SUbsection
    
    # Section 2
```

The output file (pdf) will have the following numeration:

```
1 Section 1
1.1 Subsection
2 Section 2
```

If I have a 2nd file like:

```
 ---
 title: Title
 number_sections: true
 output: latex
 graphics: yes
 header-includes:
   - '\usepackage{graphics}'
 ---
    
    # Section 3
```

The output file (pdf) will have the following numeration:

```
1 Section 3
```

But I wanted it to be like:

```
3 Section 3
```

The only workaround I found for now is to repeat the content of previous files:

```
---
title: Title
number_sections: true
output: latex
graphics: yes
header-includes:
  - '\usepackage{graphics}'
---

# Section 1

## SUbsection

# Section 2

## Another subsection

\newpage

# Section 3

The new content
```

Which gives a pdf file like:

```
1 Section 1
1.1 Subsection
2 Section 2

3 Section 3
New content...
```

I would also be able to keep numeration of subsections as well.

I'm compiling with:

```
pandoc file.md -o file.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex --number-sections --highlight-style tango
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit vague, what's your desired output? Not sure it's what you want, but you could try to put something like `\setcounter{section}{3}` into your document.

Comment: @tarleb Hi, I edited the question with more details, hopefully it is more clear now...

Comment: @tarleb OK, I tried your suggestion and it works for sections. Is there an equivalent for subsections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @tarleb

```
\setcounter{section}{3}
```

and

```
\setcounter{subsection}{3}
```

get the job done manually.